# How to share data between application written in swift And Hal driver

Tags: macos, audio, driver, core-audio, hal

[image]
I have control app and Hal driver and I want to share data between them How can I done this  ?
the application written in swift and Hal driver in c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPC to communicate with your Audio Server Plugin. See [QA1811](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1811/_index.html) for more info and code samples.

However that document doesn't mention that you can also define your own `AudioObjectPropertySelector`s and send a few `CoreFoundation` objects back and forth between your ASP and any app that can call `CoreAudio`.

There's more information on custom properties in  `AudioServerPlugInCustomPropertyInfo` in `AudioServerPlugIn.h`.

The objects you can send and receive from your ASP are:

1. `kAudioServerPlugInCustomPropertyDataTypeNone` (nothing !)
2. `kAudioServerPlugInCustomPropertyDataTypeCFString` (a string)
3. `kAudioServerPlugInCustomPropertyDataTypeCFPropertyList` (what ever you can serialise into a property list)

Comment: I'm trying XPC now but even I will send flag between the control app and Hal should I use xpc ?